# WCF wsdl not generating when deployed on server

Tags: wcf

I upgraded our wcf service from .net framework 3.5 to 4.6.2 and then deployed to server, main page is rendering fine when i click wsdl then wsdl is not generating not sure what is the reason. On my machine i tested it is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: If it's not generating the wsdl, what *is* happening when you click it?

Comment: 404 error coming